# OCAML the record field is not mutable

Tags: types, ocaml, mutable, records

I have this code:

```
type seed = {c: Graphics.color option; x : int; y : int };;
type voronoi = {dim : int * int; seeds : seed array};;

let v1 = {dim = 50,50; seeds = [| {c=Some Graphics.red; x=50; y=100}; |]}
```

when i'm trying this:

```
v1.seeds.(0).c <- Some Graphics.green;;
```

**i get this error:**

```
The record field c is not mutable
```

what can i do ?

Answer (score 3):

Record fields are immutable, unless declared otherwise. The OCaml Reference Manual ([sect 1.5](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/coreexamples.html#sec12)) says that

> Record fields can also be modified by assignment, provided they are declared `mutable` in the definition of the record type

The following should work:

```
type seed = {mutable c: Graphics.color option; x : int; y : int }
```

Answer (score 1):

indeed, c is not mutable.

You should write like this :

> ```
> v1.seeds.(0) <- {c=Some Graphics.green;x=v1.seeds.(0).x;y=v1.seeds.(0).y};;
> ```

Comment: or use the shortcut syntax `v1.seeds.(0) <- {v1.seeds.(0) with c = Some Graphics.green}` for a "functional record update".